# Look at javascript frameworks for desktop class web applications - Current mootools user

Tags: javascript, web-applications, mootools, javascript-framework

I have developed a fairly sophisticated web application using mootools over the past year, I have grown very fond of how things are done int he framework, and coming for other class based OOP languages, I feel more at home with it.

I used mootools because I knew it, but I have had to create all of my own classes for UI elements and controllers to keep track of data and do things such as auto save.

The application is very similar to google docs specifically for code, and works quite well now. But I am considering for a future rewrite that I want to start over because I have learned so much in the process, I could do it much better.

I was wondering what framework you would recommend for something like this. I have looked at cappuccino, and something like this that has UI elements already coded is very enticing, but if im going to learn a new frame work maybe it should be something like DOJO where I can use it for general web development as well.

I doubt it matters, but I use php as the DB gateway to deliver JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are an advanced javascript user [SproutCore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) or [ExtJs 4](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs4-beta/) are more apt for your evolution apart from the already mentioned Dojo.

Comment: Another vote for Sproutcore if you're going for desktop look and feel.